# iPhone class diagram design

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, diagram

I'm trying to design a class diagram for an iPhone application. The iPhone application is a basic app that has a couple of different views. It has the Main View, where they do most of the functions. Then there are a few more tabbed views and some settings (subviews I guess) within some views. I've looked online for examples on how to design such an iPhone app but I could only find this:

http://www.mikeziray.com/tag/class-diagram/

I know I have to have the app delegate and the mainviewcontroller. The mainView is basically the first tabbed pane. Then there's a second tab which holds stats and information and then there's another view which shows graphs which you can reach from the stats view. How would I go about creating a class diagram from this? Would I have a viewController for each of these views and then that's it? Would the "subview" be a subclass of the stats view? Would I need a viewController for the tabs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I was able to understand all you want is a simple tab bar app.

Here is how you should think of it:

1. Your App Delegate creates an instance of [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
2. Your `UITabBarController` instance will hold 3 different view controllers for each of its 3 tabs.
3. Those 3 view controllers will be your mainViewController/mainView (1º tab), your statsViewController (2º tab) and your graphViewController (3º tab).

That's it.

Comment: Cheers, that's very helpful. If the class has buttons would I put down those as variables of the class?

Comment: You could declare them in the @interface if you want to be able act on those buttons from any method inside your implementation. But if you just want to add them to a view and have them call an action method on button press, you can just declare them locally in your implementation and set their action method as you please. Normally I set them locally, not as instance variables, but it really depends on what you need.

Comment: I meant in the class diagram.

Comment: If you want the buttons to be instance variables, yes. Instance variables usually go into class diagrams, local variables usually do not.